# Basic Java program crash to debugger in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oop

I'm having an issue with this code I'm running. It switches over to debugger in eclipse and crashes. I'm running 1.7 JDK, however the project icon in the package explorer has a small lock on it if that helps.

Why is it crashing and how can i resolve it? I can't seem to see if my syntax is wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
        String text = input.nextLine();

        switch(text) {
        case "start":
            System.out.println("Machine started!");
            break;

        case "stop":
            System.out.println("Machine Stopped.");
            break;

            default:
                System.out.println("command not recognised");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse is open source  ;)

Comment: On my laptop with linux mint, debugger started to show green line only after around 1 min... On the same laptop on windows it starts on the spot.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with _crashes_? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: This code's working fine in my Eclipse Kepler. No issues.

Comment: I fixed it. I'm a tit who did not add JRE 1.8 to my installed JRE's.

Comment: @AdamJarvis Add this as an answer to the question and accept it, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to open your Eclipse in other Workspace. I think that this problem is given by the files in the Workspace folder

Answer (score 2):

Something is wrong with your Eclipse installation. Sample code works without problem in both Kepler & Luna.

Take a look in `workspace/.metadata/.log`

Comment: Could not delete the test folders but my system is windows there is there any file permission kind of thing or those files are opened somewhere behind the scenes that I don't know, and those files are jar files.